# How to fix: 'blockUI blockOverlay is covering my screen with a translucent overlay - can't click'

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, blockui

When I try to run my project on localhost I get a translucent black screen that I cant click through. I haven't changed any settings/code/setup. I know this for certain because I haven't even used the computer and the code worked fine last week. When I inspect element this is what pops up (image below):

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I have multiple backups in Ubuntu VirtualBox of the same setup in case one goes haywire. I have tried all my backups and they all have this overlay I can't click through. I have also tried different odoo projects I have been working on, even the ones that are complete and working... still the overlay. How do I get ride of this and does anyone know why it happened?

Edit: (Wanted to add info)
Ubuntu 16.04 -
Odoo 12 -
VirtualBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this question asked a few times around the internet but it's never answered and the op never comes back with a solution. It's a very simple answer so let me save you a headache:

My odoo database had expired. You have to register your subscription or buy a subscription to get the UIBlocker to disappear.

You can also change or delete the expiration date to give yourself more time in technical settings.

Hope this saves people some time it's easy to overlook.